# How to prove the product of two particular series converge.

Tags: sequences-and-series

Given that $2xy\leq x^2+y^2$ and that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n$ converge and are non-negative, how would you go about proving that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \sqrt{a_nb_n}$ converges?

Answer (score 1):

From your inequality you ahve
$$0\le \sqrt{a_nb_n} \le {a_n + b_n\over 2}.$$
Now invoke the comparison test.

Comment: Could you explain how you got that? I don't see where the RHS comes from.

Comment: Put $x = \sqrt{a_n}$ and $y = \sqrt{b_n}$ in $2xy \le x^2 + y^2.$

Comment: Got it thanks. Then the rest follows quite nicely I imagine, something along the lines of since $a_n$ and $b_n$ both converge then $\frac{a_n}{2}$ and $\frac{b_n}{2}$ converge. Therefore the sum of these is convergent and thus bounded therefore LHS is bounded and converges via the comparison test.

Comment: Is there something a bit more concrete I can use to justify "If $a_n$ converges $\implies$ $\frac{a_n}{2}$ converges" and likewise for $b_n$?

Comment: @CallumDavids If $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n$ is a convergent series with sequence of partial sums $(S_n)$ and c is any constant, then $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} c(a_n)$ also converges since its sequence of partial sums is $(c S_n)$.